# How to use 2 variables for getStyle in Phpexcel

Tags: phpexcel

I am having trouble getting this to work, I think it is a pretty easy fix. The standard way of formatting your code is like

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C3:C6')
```

However when I try to add a variable for each of the numbers I can not get it to work, here is what I have tried:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$var1.':C'.$var2)
```

but this needs a trailing '

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$var1.':C'.$var2."'")
```

Also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: maybe I should build the inside of the argument first?

Comment: `$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$var1.':C'.$var2)` should work perfectly well as long as `$var1` and `$var2` are set as numeric row values (positive integers); concatenating a trailing `'` should actually break it, and PHPExcel should throw an exception for an invalid range argument in that case

Comment: Building the range argument first shouldn't make any difference; although it's easier for you to debug and ensure that the result of your concatenation is exactly what it should be

Comment: Thanks, it did work in the end and I am unsure what was preventing it working prior, so thanks